# Why IE can't display special symbols from my HttpHandler web app properly?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, httpserver

I have a web app using Java HttpServer, jQuery/html, it deals with special symbols like : ♤ ♠ ♧

The app works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but when I use IE, it displayed the symbols as : ? ? ?

My jQuery code looks like this :

```
$(document).on('click','#Save',function()
{
  var buttonData='';
  $('button[id^=\"Current_\"]').each(function() { buttonData+=$(this).text()+' ' });
  $.get('My_App?New_Data='+buttonData,function(responseText)
  {
    $('#Save_div').html(responseText);
  });
});
```

My `HttpHandler` looks like this :

```
      public void handle(HttpExchange exchange)
      {
        OutputStream responseBody=exchange.getResponseBody();
        String requestMethod=exchange.getRequestMethod(),requestPath=exchange.getRequestURI().getPath(),New_Data;
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> params=queryToMap(exchange.getRequestURI().getRawQuery());

        try
        {
          New_Data=(params.get("New_Data")==null?null:URLDecoder.decode(params.get("New_Data"),"utf-8"));
          Headers responseHeaders=exchange.getResponseHeaders();
          responseHeaders.set("Content-Type","text/html;charset=utf-8");
          exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200,0);
          responseText=New_Data;
          responseBody.write(responseText.getBytes());
        }
...
```

What can I do to make IE display the special symbols like the other 2 browsers ?

Edit : My IE version is :11.0.96

Comment: Which version of IE are we talking about?

Comment: Looks like a Unicode issue. Did you add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the top of the `<head>`?

Comment: Nope, that's not the cause. Moreover, response header overrides meta tag. Meta tag is only used when HTML is not read via HTTP but e.g. from local disk file system via `file://`.

Comment: I'm using : import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;
 to implement a web server, so I said servlet, it functions like one, does that mean my implementation has a problem ?

Comment: It is **not** a servlet. To learn what servlets really are head over to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thanks BalusC for pointing out that this is not a servlet, I'm using the com.sun.net.httpserver.* to simulate/provide the functions of a servlet, it's definitely not a servlet from Java package, but the question is still : why IE 11 first displayed the symbols correctly, but when I clicked a button to save them into a file, it went through the above jQuery process, then displayed the symbols as ? ? ?, if some of the symbols are from regular characters like "2","a","$", they are still displayed correctly. I suspect the problem is in jQuery while passing symbols as parameters to the HttpHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found the answer.

Use encodeURIComponent() to encode the text with specials symbols then send it to the server, it worked as expected.